# execute custom JPQL query with panache on quarkus

Tags: jpql, timescaledb, quarkus-panache

we use panache in our quarkus/graphql application to access the database. It works well to filter and fetch data. And now we would like to execute custom jqpl queries, but we did not find a way to do so with panache and the active record pattern.

Why is this necessary for us? We want to use timescaledb, an extension for PostgreSQL. And to fetch aggregated data, we need to use its functions on database level.

Why not use an sql query? Our graphql interface is based on the field names in our java code. Writing sql queries would require us to use column names in filters we use for some graphql queries.

Is there a way to execute custom jqpl queries with panache?

Kind regards,
Marko

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for custom queries?

```java
@Query(
  value = "SELECT time_bucket(...), avg(temperature) FROM conditions", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<ConditionSummary> dailyTemperatureSummary();
```

I think this is a good resource to check: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

I never used panache, but I had some similar conundrum running timescale getting GQL from the Hasura layer because of the lack of types from my queries that should be registered as tables.

Long story short, I created some empty table structures to map the same types from my functions that were returning a set of rows.

Note on this specific section:
https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/tutorials/custom-timescaledb-dashboards/#building-views-for-our-timescaledb-metrics

Look that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE compressed_chunk AS
SELECT compress_chunk((c.chunk_schema ||'.' ||c.chunk_name)::regclass)
FROM   timescaledb_information.chunks c
WHERE  NOT c.is_compressed limit 0;
```

Is just a trick I'm doing to allow me to declare this function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compress_chunk_named(varchar) returns setof compressed_chunk AS ...
```

So, it's allowing Hasura to understand my function returning a set of `<table>` results that is manageable. Maybe you can approach it in a similar way for your queries.

Comment: Hi Jona, thanks for your answer. We are not using spring or spring-data, as we are working with quarkus. But I will take a look in your suggestion to create emtpy tables for the mapping. Maybe this helps to solve our issues.

Comment: Hi Marko, I was investigating, maybe this issue is related: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5348

Also good resources: https://github.com/devonfw-forge/devonfw-microservices/issues/45#issuecomment-924729069

Comment: Hi Jona, sorry for the late reply. Priorities changed in the project and we are not working on this anymore. Thank you for the links. I think they are pointing in the right direction.